# Fazer SELECT com média de avaliações dos usuários

Tags: mysql, sql, query, select

Bom, estou desenvolvendo um projeto e nele tem a lista de pessoas, eu gostaria de listar elas com base na média da avaliação, tentei fazer com INNER JOIN e AVG, mas com eles não vão mostrar usuários que acabaram de se cadastrar. O SELECT que funciona para o que eu quero é esse:

```
SELECT p.idPessoa, p.nomePessoa, p.descricaoPessoa, f.nomeFoto, 
    (SELECT SUM(a.valorAvaliacao / 
               (SELECT COUNT(a.idAvaliacao) FROM tb_avaliacao as a 
               WHERE a.idCategoria = '$idcategoria' && a.idPessoa = '$idpessoa' 
               GROUP BY a.idPessoa AND a.idCategoria)) 
    FROM tb_avaliacao as a 
    WHERE a.idCategoria = '$idcategoria' && a.idPessoa = '$idpessoa' 
    GROUP BY a.idPessoa AND a.idCategoria) as valorAvaliacao 
 FROM `tb_pessoa` as p
 INNER JOIN tb_pessoacategoria as pc ON pc.idPessoa = p.idPessoa
 INNER JOIN tb_foto as f ON pc.idPessoa = f.idPessoa and pc.idCategoria = f.idCategoria
 INNER JOIN tb_categoria as c ON c.idCategoria = pc.idCategoria
 WHERE c.idCategoria = '$idcategoria'
 GROUP BY p.idPessoa
 ORDER BY valorAvaliacao DESC, f.idFoto
```

Tem algum meio de fazer o mesmo SELECT só que sem utilizar a variável $idpessoa? Preciso que tenha uma coluna que mostre a média das avaliações recebidas, mas sem utilizar INNER JOIN entre tb_pessoa e tb_avaliacao.

[image: Modelo do BD aqui]

Comment: por que não quer usar a variável? como saber se o usuário acabou de se cadastrar? se possível, deixa também a estrutura do banco porque acredito quê seja necessário dar uma melhorada nessa query.. deve estar bem pesado o processamento..

Comment: Pois esse select deveria listar os usuários, eu não tenho o id da pessoa, o que preciso mesmo é uma coluna que mostre a média das avaliações de cada usuário, se ninguém tiver votado ainda deve aparecer 0, mas fazer isso sem dar INNER JOIN entre a tb_pessoa e a tb_avaliacao

Comment: Então seria legal informar quais os valores que esta sendo passado para as variáveis, quais as colunas que esta precisando, e passar melhor as estruturas das tabela que esta sendo usadas.

Comment: Editei e coloquei o modelo do BD

Comment: Coloque alguns dados das tabelas como texto. Coloque também um formato de saída desejado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visto que a consulta apresentada está correta e traz/traria o resultado esperado, e que o problema real é não existir a variável `$idpessoa`, pode corrigir referenciando a tabela "de fora".

`FROM tb_pessoa as p` dá à tabela `tb_pessoa` o [alias](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-alias-com-as-nomes-alternativos-para-colunas-e-tabelas-17/) `p`, que pode ser usado em uma *subconsulta*. Sendo assim, o código abaixo deve atender ao esperado:

```
SELECT p.idPessoa, p.nomePessoa, p.descricaoPessoa, f.nomeFoto, 
    (SELECT SUM(a.valorAvaliacao / 
               (SELECT COUNT(a1.idAvaliacao) FROM tb_avaliacao as a1 
               WHERE a1.idCategoria = '$idcategoria' && a1.idPessoa = p.idPessoa 
               GROUP BY a1.idPessoa AND a1.idCategoria)) 
    FROM tb_avaliacao as a 
    WHERE a.idCategoria = '$idcategoria' && a.idPessoa = p.idPessoa
    GROUP BY a.idPessoa AND a.idCategoria) as valorAvaliacao 
 FROM `tb_pessoa` as p
 INNER JOIN tb_pessoacategoria as pc ON pc.idPessoa = p.idPessoa
 INNER JOIN tb_foto as f ON pc.idPessoa = f.idPessoa and pc.idCategoria = f.idCategoria
 INNER JOIN tb_categoria as c ON c.idCategoria = pc.idCategoria
 WHERE c.idCategoria = '$idcategoria'
 GROUP BY p.idPessoa
 ORDER BY valorAvaliacao DESC, f.idFoto
```

Note que no *select* mais interno renomeei o alias da `tb_pessoa` para `a1`.

De qualquer forma, acredito que esta consulta possa ser mais trabalhada para melhorar a performance, pois faz muitas junções e *subconsultas* - talvez nem todas estas operações sejam necessárias.